# Swipeable-Cards Adapter get Item Info

Tags: android, adapter, baseadapter

I m using this framework, I already trying many times for making this problem, but I cant do it. I already asking on stackoverflow but no one cant help me. Actually I m tried.

I m using this framework : https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

And I m using SimpleCardStackAdapter like this :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {

                    final JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String id = c.getString(user_id);
                    String name = c.getString(username);
                    final String email = c.getString(text);
                    String image1 = c.getString(imageUrl);
                    String range1 = c.getString(range);
                    String msgId = c.getString(postId);
                    // adapter.add(new CardModel(name, email, image1));

                    //Set JSON Data in TextView
                    Log.i("image1image1image1image1", image1);

                    // CardModel cardModel = new CardModel(" cardModel", " CardModel", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture1));


                    card = new CardModel(name, email, image1);

                    card.setOnClickListener(new CardModel.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnClickListener() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I am pressing the card");
                            // Intent no = new Intent(HomeListview.this, YayDetailActivity.class);
                            /// startActivity(no);
                        }
                    });

                    card.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLike(CardModel card) {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I dislike the card");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDislike(CardModel card) {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I like the card");
                            // new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, card.getTitle());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), card.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    // I m added adapter
                    adapter.add(card);
                    mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
```

At the onDislike method, I need to get item name.

in this line : new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, name);

I send the item name, But it dont work.

1.How can I get the item name, in this method?
2.I have two button, one of them for onLike method, another one for onDislike Method. Ho can I triggered this two method with my button?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Decleare two variable global as string**

```
String itemname;    

try {
            JSONArray c = new JSONArray(user.toString());

            for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length();i++) {

                    String id = c.getString(user_id);
                    String name = c.getString(username);
                    final String email = c.getString(text);
                    String image1 = c.getString(imageUrl);
                    String range1 = c.getString(range);
                    String msgId = c.getString(postId);
                System.out.println("Position : " + "" + i  + ""+ c.getString(i));

                itemname = name.getString(i);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Final itemname is " + itemname);
```

Comment: For Further Need you post your json response and javacode